# How can I copy objects from one schema to another?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I need to backup objects like tables, views, procedures, functions, sequences etc from one schema to another schema in Oracle 10g.

And this need to be schedule to run daily. Is there are a way to write a program to do this?
I have been searching, and there are tools like Data Pump export/import or CTAS or toad, but these all need to be done manually.

I am looking for a programmatic way to do this.

Comment: Need to include data or just objects?

Comment: @ntalbs Need to include the data

Comment: You can schedule a script that runs an export / import (datapump)

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe I dont have the privilege to do the export/import :(

Comment: If you need to do an import / export get the privileges or get someone to do it that has the privileges. Don't reinvent the wheel because you do not have the privileges to use the tools that are specifically developed for this job.

Answer (score -1):

Ask your DBA for EXP_FULL_DATABASE,IMP_FULL_DATABASE privileges.

After that just use expdp (Export Data Pump) / impdp (Import Data Pump) utilities to perform the task.